# How can I create a to_s with an instance variable pointing to an array of objects from another class?

Tags: ruby, oop, instance-variables, puts

With the code below, I would like to create a `to_s` method that prints out information as such:

Southside has 3 team members.
Those members are: Dario, who is 22 years old. Ted, who is 21 years old. Bob, who is 44 years old.

Currently, I get this:

Southside has 3 team members.
Those members are:

```
[#<Person:0x000000025cd6e8 @name="Dario", @age=22>, #<Person:0x000000025cd670 @name="Ted", @age=21>, #<Person:0x000000025cd620 @name="Bob", @age=44>].
#<Team:0x000000025cd7d8>
```

The part I'm finding difficult is accessing the instance variables of the Person class objects that are in the Team members array.

Here are the two classes:

```
class Team
  attr_accessor :name, :members

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @members = []
  end

  def <<(person)
    members.push person
  end

  def to_s
    puts "#{@name} has #{@members.size} team members."
    puts "Those members are: #{@members}."
  end
end

class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :age

  def initialize(name, age)
    @name = name
    @age = age
  end
end

south_side_bowlers = Team.new("Southside")

south_side_bowlers << Person.new("Dario", 22)
south_side_bowlers << Person.new("Ted", 21)
south_side_bowlers << Person.new("Bob", 44)

puts south_side_bowlers
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `to_s` (`"#{@name}, who is #{@age} years old"`) for the `Person` class. Then you can do `@members.map{ |m| m.to_s}.join('. ')`

Comment: Murad, that works well. A question: is the 'to_s' in 'm.to_s' unnecessary?

Comment: @user169320 You can do `@members.map(&:to_s).join('. ')` if you want.

Comment: user169320, Murad is suggesting the you change the second line of `Team#to_s` to `"Those members are: #{@members.map{ |m| m.to_s}.join('. ')}."` (as well as adding `Person#to_s`)

Answer (score 1):

First off, you don't want to have `puts` in a `to_s` method. Instead just return the string. Second, the variable `members` is probably not actually what you want outputted in the method. Try this instead

```
def to_s
  %Q(#{@name} has #{@members.size} team members. Those members are #{@members.map{|i| "#{i.name} who is #{i.age}"}.join(', ')})
end
```

Comment: I prefer this approach to @Murad's as adding the method `Person#to_s` is both unnecessary and potentially confusing to readers who look only at the coding of the class `Person`. Eli, why `%Q(...)` rather than just double quotes?